# Multiple columns on same series. Highchart

Tags: highcharts

I would like to have a chart that represent data like this.
[image]

the series code would be something like this.

`series: [{
  name: 'Car 1',
  data: [[1, 3], [4, 6], [7, 9]]
}, {
  name: 'Car 2',
  data: [[2, 3], [8, 10], [12, 18]]
}]`

The first number on each array would be the starting point and the second the finishing point, and all arrays inside the main array would be on the same line.

Comment: Do you need a stacked bar chart 
 https://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/vnx2ghgv/2/ or kind of a columrange?

Comment: It would be kind of a column range, but it should support multiple ranges in same column like the image

Comment: You need to use a `column range` serie or `experimental gantt`.

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/columnrange

Gantt:

http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/804783-gantt-chart

Answer (score 2):

An inverted columnrange chart should work.  Your data isn't formatted in a way that would work with what you want, but transforming it isn't difficult.  If you aren't stuck with the data format you showed, you just need a point object with x, low, and high.

For example:

```
{
    x: 1,
    low: 0,
    high: 4
}
```

The following massages your current structure into the correct format:

```
$(function () {

    var series = [{
        name: 'Car 1',
        data: [
            [1, 3],
            [4, 6],
            [7, 9]
        ]
    }, {
        name: 'Car 2',
        data: [
            [2, 3],
            [8, 10],
            [12, 18]
        ]
    }, {
        name: 'Car 3',
        data: [
            [5, 9],
            [1, 2]
        ]
    }];

    // massage the data
    var data = [];
    for(var i=0;i<series.length;i++) {
        for(var j=0;j<series[i].data.length;j++) {
             data.push({
                 x: j, 
                 low: series[i].data[j][0],
                 high: series[i].data[j][1],
                 name: series[i].name
             });
        }
    }

    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'columnrange',
            inverted: true
        },

        plotOptions: {
            columnrange: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Cars',
            data: data
        }]

    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hqwrx4uy/